# MySQLdb for Python - incompatible library version error?

Tags: python, mysql, django, installation

I am, like many others, trying to get MySQLdb for Python to run on Mac Snow Leopard (10.6.x) and I've been able to install the 64-bit MySQL DMG as recommended by various blogs/forum posts, and I've been able to install the setuptools and MySQLDB itself by using the

```
ARCHFLAGS='-arch 86_64' python2.7 setup.py clean
ARCHFLAGS='-arch 86_64' python2.7 setup.py build
sudo ARCHFLAGS='-arch 86_64' python2.7 setup.py install
```

As you can see from the above I have upgraded to Python 2.7 and everything seems fine; except when I try to import MySQLdb into python shell.

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ad/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ad/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _mysql.so requires version 17.0.0 or later, but libmysqlclient.16.dylib provides version 16.0.0
```

I did a search and found libmysqlclient.16.dylib but not libmysqlclient.17.dylib

What is causing this problem, how do I resolve it, and even though I did a search for libmysqlclient.17.dylib there seems to be nothing about it; does it exist?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to get past this?  I'm hitting the same thing.

Comment: No. I gave up. Also my system still uses Python 2.6 and has all the references to it too.  I tried forcing it to use Python 2.7 but I do not think MySQLdb works for 2.7.x. In the end I gave up and just used SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You built the module against MySQL 5.5.x, but only the client libraries for 5.1.x are available on the system. Either install updated libraries, or build against an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely make sure that Python and MySQL are for the same architecture. You have to consistently use either 32bit or 64bit versions for both.
Also make sure that MySQLdb can find the MySQL libraries and includes, but from your error message it seems like this is the case.